# Back-ground image showing

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, background-image

I want to add a background image to my Project but it is not working

I tried to add a background image globally but it is not working
this is nextjs index page

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
export default function index() {
  return (
       <div className="myindex">
            dcmkl
       </div>
  )
}
this is global.css file
```

type here

```
.myclass{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  background-image: url('./pexels-johannes-plenio-1103970.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store local images is the `public` folder (and its subfolders) in the root directory of your project. You can import an image from that place into your page or component like so:

```
import someImage from '../public/some-path.jpg'
```

Then apply inline style:

```
<div style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${someImage})`,
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
}}>
</div>
```